# Issue with installing npm bootstrap

Tags: node.js, npm, bootstrap-4

I have installed the following version of bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3
```

included this line of code `require("bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less")` in abc.js file, when I am trying to compile the code I am getting

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
```

error.Please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Why would you install 4.0.0 Alpha 3 today? It's an ALPHA! And 4.1.0 is out and stable!

Comment: Also why are you requiring a LESS file? It isn't a JavaScript module.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes it is a JavaScript module. I have tried it din't work.

Comment: `bootstrap.less` is not a JavaScript module. It is a stylesheet written in the [Less stylesheet language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)). Do not confuse it with `less.js` which is a processor written in JS that converts LESS to CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First way (difficult)**

You need to install the latest version Bootstrap 4

`npm install bootstrap`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#npm

Import Bootstrap’s SASS by adding this line to your app’s entry point (usually index.js or app.js):

`import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/#importing-styles

Import Bootstrap’s JavaScript by adding this line to your app’s entry point (usually index.js or app.js):

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

or indicate the path completely

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

or if you prefer require()

```
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
```

Alternatively, you may import plugins individually as needed:

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
...
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript

**Second way (easy)**

Just plug in ready-made js and css to your page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```